# Explanation needed on Classloader

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

I am having a directory having jar files.  In which some classes are available in more than one jar file.

```
List<URL> jarsToLoad = new ArrayList<URL>();
File jarDir = new File("Directory name having jar files");
for ( File jarFile : jarDir.listFiles())
{
    jarsToLoad.add( new URL("file", null, jarFile.getPath()) );
}
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new URLClassLoader(jarsToLoad.toArray(new URL[jarsToLoad.size()])));
```

jarDir.listFiles() is listing jars in different order while executing the above code in different machines.  Suppose if Test.class is present in A.jar and B.jar in some machines Test.class is getting loaded from A.jar in some machines it is getting loaded form B.jar, based on which jar is listed first(JAVA API documentation say's listFiles() method won't guarantee any specific listing order).

Suppose if both A.jar & B.jar is present in tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/lib directory from which jar tomcat will load Test.class.

I need explanation on how tomcat is loading the classes from jar files in this specific scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Its java native call.

So we dont have control on it.

So you use sort before doing process.

You can write your own `Comparator` to sort it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am trying to replicate tomcat class loader behaviour.  I want to know whether tomcat is doing any such sorting, if so how they are sorting it (In alphabetical order or sorting it using some other parameters)?

Answer (score 1):

here it's all you need to know

> http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html